# How to split ArrayList by object attribute in java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am writing a program to optimize a transportation system.
I have an ArrayList "passengers" of 65,000 passengers, and each passenger has an hour attribute (1-24), among other attributes.
I want to go through the ArrayList and create 24 new ArrayLists of passengers based on their hour, so that I can work with each list to find the transportation needed for each hour.

```
//example of what I want to do for passengers in each hour
if (passengers.get(i).getAge() == 'C') {
    if (passengers.get(i).getTransportation() == 'S')
        subwayCount += 0.75;
    else if (passengers.get(i).getTransportation() == 'G')
        goTrainCount += 0.75;
    else if (passengers.get(i).getTransportation() == 'X')
        streetCarCount += 0.75;
    else if (passengers.get(i).getTransportation() == 'C')
        busCount += 0.75;
    else 
        goBusCount += 0.75;                 

}
```

Comment: If i understand do you need to group by arraylist of passengers based on hour attribute? it's  not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the hour attribute to get a Map like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Passenger>> hourToPassengersMap = passengers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Passenger::getHour));
```

Use it like:

```
List<Passenger> hour3Passengers = hourToPassengersMap.get(3);
```